# Rest Easy Hello world example showing 404 not found error

Tags: rest, maven, wildfly, resteasy

As I didn't found any good tutorial for RestEasy + WildFly, I'm following this (https://robferguson.org/blog/2016/12/02/getting-started-with-resteasy/) tutorial and created a simple Hello World example of JAX-RS project using Resteasy 3.7.0.Final + Wildfly 13 + Java 8 + maven. This tutorial is actually using Jetty Http server.

Here is the Resource class :

```
@Path("/hello")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
public class MessageResource {

    @GET
    @Path("/{param}")
    public Response printMessage(@PathParam("param") String msg) {
        String result = "Hello " + msg + "!";
        return Response.status(200).entity(result).build();
    }
}
```

And a class extending `javax.ws.rs.core.Application` - (all Rest resources will be registered by this class automatically)

```
@ApplicationPath("")
public class HelloWorldApplication extends Application {

    public HelloWorldApplication() {}

    @Override
    public Set<Object> getSingletons() {
        HashSet<Object> set = new HashSet<Object>();
        set.add(new MessageResource());
        return set;
    }
}
```

In addition I have added jboss-deployment-structure.xml (which is not part of the tutorial) under WEB-INF to exclude the following modules :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclude-subsystems>
            <subsystem name="resteasy" />
        </exclude-subsystems>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="javaee.api" />
            <module name="javax.ws.rs.api"/>
            <module name="org.jboss.resteasy.resteasy-jaxrs" />
        </exclusions>
        <local-last value="true" />
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

I suppose this excludes resteasy modules bundled with Wildfly (please correct me if I'm wrong), since I'm using latest version of RestEasy in pom.xml :

```
<properties>
    <resteasy.version>3.7.0.Final</resteasy.version>
</properties>
```

In maven configuration I have removed the jetty plugin, and rest of the part in pom.xml is same as in tutorial example here, except the RestEasy version.
https://github.com/Robinyo/resteasy/blob/master/examples/helloworld/pom.xml

But when I try to run the example with URL http://localhost:8080/hello/World, I'm getting `404 - Not Found` error.

Is there any part missing in maven configuration or wildfly configuration?